# Webpack - how to import script with async function

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack for first time and I am trying to import file confirmModal.js with async function inside. But I'm getting this error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined* after compilation and test in browser. Every other scripts and styles is included and work fine.

Is there someone who can advise me, what I'm doing wrong? I've tried everything, but without success. It looks like the file confirmModal is ignored for some reason.

versions of packages:

```
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
"webpack": "^5.25.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
"core-js": "^2.6.12"
```

ConfirmModal.js

```js
const ui = {
    confirm: async (message) => createConfirm(message)
}
```

my app.js file:

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
import './moneyModal';
import './eventModal';
import './taskModal';
import 'jquery-cropper'
import './confirmModal';

ui.confirm("Asdf");
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const miniCssExtract = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'main.css'
});

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ['./www/js/app.js'],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'www/dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: './www/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            {
                                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                                "corejs": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    ],
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            //use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader?url=false'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [
                                [
                                    'autoprefixer',
                                    {
                                        // Options
                                    },
                                ],
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            test: /\.html/,
            use: 'raw-loader'
        },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        miniCssExtract,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            Nette: 'nette-forms',
            'window.Nette': 'nette-forms'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't see any exports in `ConfirmModal.js`.

Comment: Ok. You have right. I forgot about it. Thank you